# Apply CSS style to sub menus

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am changing the featured header background for all my product categories on my Wordpress site with CSS. I want the style to apply to all sub-categories from the parent category.

For example I have the category "Candy" that gets this header image:

```
  .term-candy .shop-page-title.category-page-title.dark.featured-title.page-title{
    background-image: url(PICTURE-URL.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I want the same style to be applied to all child categories of "Candy". For example, one of the child categories of "Candy" is "Gummies". I've tried adding .term-gummies to the CSS but I don't think that's correct:

```
  .term-candy .term-gummies .shop-page-title.category-page-title.dark.featured-title.page-title{
    background-image: url(PICTURE-URL.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I have about more than 5 sub-categories per category so writing a bunch of CSS for each sub-category would make everything too cluttered.

Comment: Can you show what your HTML looks like for the product categories?

Comment: Which part of the HTML do you want to see?

Comment: The product categories, meaning parent category and sub-categories.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure exactly which part of the HTML to show..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have every element that has the class ".term-gummies" the same style as your ".term-candy .shop-page-title.category-page-title.dark.featured-title.page-title" expression, than you must not add "term-gummies" to that CSS path.

You need to make an own CSS style entry for that class, like:

```
.term-gummies .shop-page-title.category-page-title.dark.featured-title.page-title {
    background-image: url(PICTURE-URL.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You can avoid duplication by adding more CSS paths to one expression, like:

```
.term-candy .shop-page-title.category-page-title.dark.featured-title.page-title, 
.term-gummies .shop-page-title.category-page-title.dark.featured-title.page-title {
    background-image: url(PICTURE-URL.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: If you want to know why, you should read about CSS selectors (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and DOM (https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/DOM) :)